# How to write Nested query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm newbie in MySQL and I'm not getting how to write query for my problem. I have a table named "Station" and there is one column named "City". I'm trying to find a maximum and minimum length of city name from Station.

Conditions are -

1. You have to sort city names first in ascending order.
2. Find a string of maximum and minimum in length from sorted table result.
3. If there are more than one rows of same length of string then pick first one only.
4. Show result as *city_name size_of_city_name*

Comment: Hint: `ORDER BY LENGTH(city)`

Comment: I tried but I'm not getting how to frame query

Comment: Or you can use `SELECT MAX(LENGTH(city)), MIN(LENGTH(city))`

Comment: There are only so many hints we can give without actually doing your homework for you.

Comment: ORDER BY LENGTH(city) is invalid.

Comment: @Barmar I'm asking for a way. I already figured out which things I can use. There are many ways to do this. Out of that one is use of Nested query but it's out of my sense of knowledge. I searched here on stackoverflow too but didn't get anything. Please tell me how can I fit all these conditions in one. I tried IN operator and UNION for joining two queries. But that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*
 FROM ( 
     select City, length( City )
     from Station
     where length( City ) = ( select max( length( City ) ) from Station )
     order by city
     limit 1 
   ) a
UNION ALL 
SELECT b.*
 FROM ( 
     select City, length( City )
     from Station
     where length( City ) = ( select min( length( City ) ) from Station )
     order by city
     limit 1
) b;
```

you can edit the max to min to get the min length of the city

I think if you want it in one query it will be more complex

[sqlfiddle to test the query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca59c/9)

Comment: This is only one query but I want both min and max length results in one query. I used UNION but it didn't work.

Comment: I updated the answer to union both queries

Comment: Thanks friend. But can you describe it? I am not getting why you used that a.* and b.*. Can you please describe it?

Comment: a.* to show all columns in the nested query table "a" the same for b